# out of/through a door

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Chris was walking down the hall when suddenly a man ran **out of** / **through** a door.

1. Are **out of** and **through** the options I have here?
2. Are they equally common?
3. Would **came running out of/through** also be natural?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the same image from both sentences, and "came running" is also correct.

The man that ran through a door could have been running *into* a room.
Pragmatically this is unlikely (since if Chris is in the hall, she sees the man suddenly he must come out of the room)

Google suggests both are similarly common, which matches my intuition.

It would perhaps be better to say either "through a doorway" or "out of a room".  Although I'd understand your versions with "door", the person doesn't come out of, or through a *door*, since door is a solid piece of wood. A doorway is the passage that is filled by a door.